# How to Store multiple dictionary in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I have two Viewcontrollers in FirstVC i build 5 `UITextField` for registration ,this TextField value are stroed in dictionary finally the dictionary stored in `NSUserdefault` then in SecondVC i want to show this data
My problem is that each time when i add new discretionary in `NSUserdefault` The old one dictionary was replaced 
i want data of all dictionary.

***below is code of my FirstVC***

```
  -(void)btnReg

{ 
//data add in disctionary
    for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        UITextField *txtTemp=(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
        [discRege setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count] forKey:@"no"];
        [discRege setObject:txtTemp.text forKey:[arraylblName objectAtIndex:i-1]];
    }
//dictionary add in nsuserdefault

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:discRege forKey:@"ABC"];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

//push to SecondVc
    secondViewController *objSec=[[secondViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objSec animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:false];

}
```

***below is code of my SecondVC***

```
ArratTemp  =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"ABC"] ;
    if (!ArratTemp )
    {
        ArratTemp =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    else
    {
        ArratTemp = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"ABC"]mutableCopy];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",ArratTemp);
```

Comment: Basically it's pretty bad programming habit to use user defaults for passing data between view controllers.

Comment: Yes, @vadian is right, you can directly pass data to other viewcontrollers. no need to use userdefaults

Comment: yes i know that but i just want to learn Nsuserdefault that's why i use it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you are using the same key and replacing the existing dictionary object...

```
// Using the same key will overwrite the last saved dictionary.
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:discRege forKey:@"ABC"];
```

Instead of storing it as a dictionary, store it as an array of dictionaries. Whenever you add new registration, fetch the saved array, add new dictionary object into it and update the userDefaults with that array.

```
mutableArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"ABC"] mutableCopy];
[mutableArray addObject:discReg];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:mutableArraay forKey:@"ABC"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the same disctionary every time.

You have two solutions :

**Solution 1.**

Store different dictionaries under different keys, not all under "ABC". So in your `for loop` can use the index (`i`) to have multiple entries, instead of just ABC every time. Here it's a simple matter you can resolve yourself. Make sure to not store everything under the same Key, and you'll find them ;) For example, you could save under `[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]`and then browse your NSUserDefaults for 0, 1, 2, 3... and so on. I recommend against this btw, solution 2 is the way to go.

**Solution 2.**

Store all your dictionaries in an array, and then store the array in the NSUserDefaults.

For that, simply create an `NSMutableArray` that you keep empty, then add dictionaries in it !

```
NSMutableArray dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        //Creating new dictionary
        NSMutableDictionary *currentDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        //Getting the text we want
        UITextField *txtTemp =(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
        NSString *text = txtTemp.text;

        //This is here because you had it
        [currentDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count] forKey:@"no"];

        //All dictionaries will have key = name of the Label,
        //but you could change it to something static, like
        // "Content" for example. It'll be easier to find later
        [currentDict setObject:text forKey:[arraylblName objectAtIndex:i-1]];

        //Adding that newly formed dictionary to the mutable array.
        [dataArray addObject:currentDict];
    }

  //Adding the array containing dictionaries to the NSUSerDefaults
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:dataArray forKey:@"ABC"];
```

Note : I'm not exactly sure what you're doing with the dictionaries in the for loop, but since you didn't show the code, I'm guessing its' not part of the question. With my answer you have enough information to make some corrections if needed. All you need to remember is :

1. Create a dictionary per answer, and not one for all
2. Put each dictionary in the same array
3. Save the array (containing all the dictionaries)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer .. i use your second solution but Now problem is that it will add same dictionary many time and i want different dictionary ................                                                                                          means when i add dictionary first time array contain it and when i add second dictionary array contain same(lastone) dictionary 2 times but i want to store 1st dictionary as well ass second dictionary

Comment: Check my code in the answer. Are you sure you're creating a new dictionary every time? Notice I didn't use your `discRege`, I created my `currentDic†`instead. It's a new object created every time,**inside** the loop. If it's created there, and added **to the array, not the nsuserdefaults**, you'll be fine.
Only at the end of the loop you will **add the array (not the dictionary) to nsuserdefault**